# Importing does not seem to work python and returns "ModuleNotFoundError" even though module is installed

Tags: python

Currently I'm trying to install tensorflow with pip, I've used the following command to install it with:

`pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow` which after installing returns `Successfully installed tensorflow-2.5.0`. But when I install I get a lot of notices "Requirement already satisfied" but I'm unsure if this is normal or not.

I have a following local python file on my Windows 10 computer called `test.py` and inside is a simple import

**test.py**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

When I run python I get the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

When I run `pip3 list` I can see that the module tensorflow is there, but importing it does give the error. It seems to happen with other modules too, as I've tried installing `pymongo` and it gave me the same error.

**What I've tried**

1. Uninstalling, re-installing python
2. Uninstalling and re-installing tensorflow

Python3 version: 3.9.5
Pip3 version: 21.1.1

Comment: Did you install the library into one virtual environment, then attempt to use it in another?

Comment: try to check "pip list" first

Answer (score 0):

I would try `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`. Running pip as a module ensures the versions are the same and can help with compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have installed `tensorflow` on python3(guessing after seeing pip3 command) but you are running script on python2 (guessing after seeing "When I run python").

Assuming you aren't using virtualenv

Try running
`python3 test.py`
If this didnt help then try below command.

```
python3.x test.py # where x could be your minor version Ex: python3.6/python3.7
```